# pandas.to_json output date format in specific form

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime

The original form of date in dataframe is:

```
Date                                                                   
2018-09-17          12.83  12.92  12.38  12.65         12.65  1937329.0
2018-09-10          12.92  13.12  12.81  12.83         12.83  1150470.0
```

After converted to json, `df.to_json(orient='index',date_format='iso')`
it looks like this:

```
"2018-09-17T00:00:00Z":{"
```

any way to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest fix is to first convert your `datetime` series to an `object` dtype series of strings:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I advise you only do this as a final step prior to json conversion, as you lose benefits of vectorised computations and likely will see less efficient memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

the first one is in case you get an error in this part ".dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')"

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this alternative:

```
df = pd.read_json('test.json')
df['date_hour'] = [datetime.strptime(date[0:10],'%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in 
df['date_hour']]
```

You can read more in my answer on a similar topic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56280982/11222127