# How to convert date to json serialization?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with dates like: `2017-11-23 12:05:26`. I need to serialize the dataframe into a json lines file. I am using

```
df.to_json('df.jsonl', orient='records', lines=True, date_format='iso')
```

The problem is that the date changes in the jsonl file, becoming like this:

```
2017-11-23 12:05:26.000005
```

How can I preserve the date format, without the seconds changing?

Comment: same problem? You can try the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730953/pandas-to-json-output-date-format-in-specific-form